# ubuntu 12.10 xorg loads cpu core at 100% percent

Tags: 12.10, xorg, cpu-load

ubuntu 12.10 xorg loads cpu core at 100% percent

Not related to snd_ca0106.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The high usage problem on lubuntu 12.10 turned out to be a snd_ca0106 soundblaster card.
The cpu ran at 25-35 percent with nothing but the desktop, I watched it with htop and conky for a couple of days and the computer was very slow. When i did a 
cat /proc/interrupts the irq 16 showed up with "uhci_hdc:usb2, i915, snd_ca0106".
the number of interrupts was 1916656972 compared to 1780 on another computer with no 
ca0106 card in it. I removed the sound card and the problem was solved, so it might be caused by some type of hardware. If it is not a removable item you can reassign irq's.

Comment: Not related to snd_ca0106. I have no such driver loaded.